# Monitor accesses to directory on a Linux machine

Tags: files, security, monitoring, audit

How would you monitor a directory on a Linux machine to check if there was a user (or someone from the network) who attempted to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[inotify](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) like so

```
inotifywait -m -e modify,create,delete -r /var/www >> /var/log/i-see-www 2>&1
```

assuming you meant "*worked in*" when you said "*access*", simply listing or reading files .. that'd be harder to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `auditd` (`audit`) to monitor file access , after starting the service a log file will be registered under `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

To set a watch on a file, run :

```
sudo auditctl -w /path/to/file
```

To check it , run:

```
sudo ausearch -f /path/to/file
```

A detailled tuto can be found on [Arch-linux-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Audit_framework)